# Hibernate: insert in entity using select with named parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, insert-into

I have a very specific problem in which I must do something like (in HQL):

```
insert into EntityA(field1, field2, field3, field4, field5)
select
    :paramForField1, 
    :paramForField2,
    :paramForField3,
    :paramForField4,
    :paramForField5
from 
    EntityB
where 
    ...
```

The parameters are being passed using `Query.setParameter(String, Object)` ([JavaDoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))) and they are String, String, String, Date and an Enum.

Although the parameter number is right (five parameters for five fields), Hibernate keeps raising the following exception:

```
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: number of select types did not match those for insert [insert into ...]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IntoClause.validateTypes(IntoClause.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.InsertStatement.validate(InsertStatement.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.postProcessInsert(HqlSqlWalker.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.insertStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:513)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1651)
    ...
```

I'm using Hibernate 3.3.2 GA.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with hibernate 4.3 this is possible. Versions before hibernate 4.3 did not support parameters in the select clause.

Comment: Good to know!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
Class<?> entityAClass = EntityA.class;

Field field1 = entityAClass.getDeclaredField("paramForField1");
field1.setAccessible(true); 
String paramForField1 = field1.getName();

Field field2 = entityAClass.getDeclaredField("paramForField2");
field2.setAccessible(true); 
String paramForField2 = field2.getName();

Field field3 = entityAClass.getDeclaredField("paramForField3");
field3.setAccessible(true); 
String paramForField3 = field3.getName();

String hqlInsert = String.format(
    "insert into EntityA(%1$s, %2$s, %3$s)" + 
    "select c.%1$s, c.%2$s, c.%3$s from EntityB b" + 
    "where ...", 
    paramForField1, paramForField2, paramForField3);
int createdEntities = s.createQuery( hqlInsert )
    .executeUpdate();
```

Hibernate doesn't support parametrized INSERTs or SELECTs. You can use parameters in the WHERE clause only.

Any SQL string formatting  is susceptible to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), that's why you need to use the Java Reflection idiom I suggested. If you don't supply a valid EntityA field name, then the field won't be resolved and an exception will be thrown.

This way you can build a dynamic query and also make sure you don't expose your code to SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, "paramForFieldX" represents the value for the fieldX and not the field itself. Thus I couldn't imagine how could the reflection make my code SQL Injection proof.

Comment: I guess ";DROP TABLE EntityA;" won't be resolved as a class filed, right? But using string concatenation, one could easily drop your database.

Comment: As I said, paramForFieldX is the value for the field. Just think about a "title" field of a News entity. My entity's field is named "title", but the "paramForTitleField" might be something like "Java Rocks". Thus, the reflection using the paramForTitleField would never work.

Comment: According to your SQL query, it makes no sense. Your select is: "select :paramForField1 from EntityB". So ":paramForField1" can only be a field of EntityB. Hence the solution I gave you.

Comment: Actually, it does make sense.
Just imagine the following native SQL:

SELECT
 'a',
 1
FROM
 MyTable

This is a correct SQL.

Comment: Yes, but JPQL and HQL are entity based query languages. Maybe you need native queries after all.

Comment: Yes. It seems Hibernate lack support for this kind of query. I would like to use Hibernate for a specific feature it provides me. In the end I just used JDBC.

Comment: I see. Even if you chose a different solution, do you consider accepting this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that Hibernate is not prepared for this. Why you need to set the column names of table EntityB as parameters? Did you think of just concatenating the query string?

Comment: The parameters have absolutaly no relation to EntityB. EntityB is just a "hard-coded" table that has only one row. It was made so the insert inserted one or zero lines, accordingly to the result of the select. It must be like this to guarantee atomicity of the operation. The problem of concatenating the strings is that it would be succeptible to SQL Injection.